# How to check self-descriptive number in c++?

Tags: c++

In mathematics, a self-descriptive number is an integer m that in a given base b is b digits long in which each digit d at position n (the most significant digit being at position 0 and the least significant at position b - 1) counts how many instances of digit n are in m. 

For example, in base 10, the number 6210001000 is self-descriptive because of the following reasons:

In base 10, the number has 10 digits, indicating its base; 
It contains `6` at position `0`, indicating that there are six 0s in `6210001000`; 
It contains `2` at position `1`, indicating that there are two 1s in `6210001000`; 
It contains `1` at position `2`, indicating that there is one `2` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `0` at position `3`, indicating that there is no `3` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `0` at position `4`, indicating that there is no `4` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `0` at position `5`, indicating that there is no `5` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `1` at position `6`, indicating that there is one `6` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `0` at position `7`, indicating that there is no `7` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `0` at position `8`, indicating that there is no `8` in `6210001000`; 
It contains `0` at position 9, indicating that there is no `9` in `6210001000`. 

 I tried to check it by doing this, Assumed that user will not enter a number greater than `6210001000`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main (){
 int n;
 cin >> n;
 if (n == 1210 || n == 2020 || n == 21200 || n == 3211000 || n == 42101000 || n == 521001000 || n == 6210001000)
    cout << "self-descriptive" << endl;
 else
    cout << "not self-descriptive" << endl;


return 0;
}
```

How can I do that in a different way that compares each digit with if it describes or not?

Comment: Use modulus, division, loops, and a map containing counts of each digit encountered.

Answer (score 0):

With a help of STL containers and algorithms you can do it easyly. Here is an example which separated to digits and then analyzes all digits as you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void Trace( std::vector<int16_t> vec, const std::string& title = "" )
{
    if ( !title.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << title << std::endl;
    }
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int16_t>(std::cout,","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // You can input here
    int64_t InputNumber;
    InputNumber = 6210001000;

    int64_t TempInputNumber = InputNumber;
    const int64_t BASE = 10;
    //Vector of digits
    std::vector<int16_t> VecDigits;


    while ( (TempInputNumber / float(BASE)) > 0 )
    {
        int16_t Dig = TempInputNumber % BASE;
        VecDigits.push_back( Dig );
        TempInputNumber /= BASE;
    }

    Trace(VecDigits, "Digits separated");

    //Reverse separated digits if needed
    std::vector<int16_t> VecReversedDigits;
    std::reverse_copy(VecDigits.begin(), VecDigits.end(), std::back_inserter(VecReversedDigits));

    Trace(VecReversedDigits, "Digits reversed");

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < VecReversedDigits.size(); i++ )
    {
        size_t CountDigits = std::count(VecReversedDigits.begin(), VecReversedDigits.end(), i);
        std:: cout << "It contains " << VecReversedDigits[i] << " at position " << i <<", indicating that there is " << CountDigits << " digits(" << i << ") at " << InputNumber << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Digits separated
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,6,
Digits reversed
6,2,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
It contains 6 at position 0, indicating that there is 6 digits(0) at 6210001000
It contains 2 at position 1, indicating that there is 2 digits(1) at 6210001000
It contains 1 at position 2, indicating that there is 1 digits(2) at 6210001000
It contains 0 at position 3, indicating that there is 0 digits(3) at 6210001000
It contains 0 at position 4, indicating that there is 0 digits(4) at 6210001000
It contains 0 at position 5, indicating that there is 0 digits(5) at 6210001000
It contains 1 at position 6, indicating that there is 1 digits(6) at 6210001000
It contains 0 at position 7, indicating that there is 0 digits(7) at 6210001000
It contains 0 at position 8, indicating that there is 0 digits(8) at 6210001000
It contains 0 at position 9, indicating that there is 0 digits(9) at 6210001000
Program ended with exit code: 0
```